# What is the purpose of "SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1" that SQLAlchemy performs?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I can see that SQLAlchemy is doing requests like

```
SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
```

that show up in my query history in SnowflakeDB.

What is SQLAlchemy trying to achieve with those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the [What's new in SQLAlchemy 1.3](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_13.html#convert-unicode-parameters-deprecated):

> Once Python 3 was introduced, DBAPIs began to start supporting Unicode
> more fully, and more importantly, by default.  However, the conditions
> under which a particular DBAPI would or would not return Unicode data
> from a result, as well as accept Python Unicode values as parameters,
> remained extremely complicated. This was the beginning of the
> obsolescence of the "convert_unicode" flags, because they were no
> longer sufficient as a means of ensuring that encode/decode was
> occurring only where needed and not where it wasn't needed. Instead,
> "convert_unicode" started to be automatically detected by dialects.
> Part of this can be seen in the "SELECT 'test plain returns'" and
> "SELECT 'test_unicode_returns'" SQL emitted by an engine the first
> time it connects; **the dialect is testing that the current DBAPI with
> its current settings and backend database connection is returning
> Unicode by default or not.**